# c - compile main file with source files and header

Tags: c, compilation

I'm trying to compile a main file that uses a header. I have all of the files in my directory: card.c, deck.c header.h, and main.c
[image]

The issue is that when i do gcc main.c I get this: [image]

It seems like it's not recognizing the source and header files so my compiling commands are missing something. Thanks

Comment: What is the exact command you are using to compile your program?

Comment: gcc main.c. Do I need to gcc the header and other source files first?

Comment: What are your "compiling commands"?

Comment: You are required to post text as text, not images!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have source files `card.c`, `deck.c`, and `main.c`.  It is reasonable to suppose that `card.c` and `deck.c` each define functions, at least one of which is called by something in `main.c`, else there would be no need for your `header.h`.  Presumably, the functions named in your link errors are among those.

The command

> ```
> gcc main.c
> ```

attempts to compile the code in `main.c` and link it to form a complete program, but it is not enough for a complete program because some of the needed functions are defined (implemented) in other source files.  That's what the linker is complaining about.

If you want to compile `main.c` to an object file but not link it, then you need the `-c` option:

```
gcc -c main.c
```

If you want to build a complete program with one run of `gcc` then you must specify all the needed sources:

```
gcc main.c deck.c card.c
```

In the latter case, you might also want to use the `-o` option to specify a name different from `a.out` for the executable.

Answer (score 0):

You should put all your .c files as inputs to `gcc`. You can find lots of documentation for gcc with the Google. For example: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_11.html.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for this link. I did gcc main.c deck.c card.c and the output file rules perfectly with ./main